# AngularJS: How ng-model binds the data to html when it should be otherwise?

Tags: angularjs-ng-model

I learnt that ng-model binds the html values to application data. But in below eg, where application data is predefined, it outputs the data to html. How/why is this happening? 
eg: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_directives

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the magical world of [Angular expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression), the docs should have all the info you neeed